# Java bit-shift results in negative number

Tags: java, bit-shift

I am trying to make a method to use bit shifting to convert bytes to their hex (as a char) equivalent.  However, I am experiencing some unexpected results: some of the numbers come back as negative.  I understand that Java does not have the equivalent of unsigned integers, and I am at a loss as to how to make this work.  Here is my code:

```
final static char[] hex_val = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] bytes = {(byte) 0x58, (byte) 0x6D, (byte) 0x8F, (byte) 0xBA, (byte) 0xF5, (byte) 0x81};

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Run: " + i);
        System.out.println("First nibble: " + hex_val[(bytes[i] >> 4)]);
        System.out.println("Second nibble: " + hex_val[(bytes[i] & 0xf)]);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

> Run: 0
>   First nibble: 5
>   Second nibble: 8
>   Run: 1
>   First nibble: 6
>   Second nibble: D
>   Run: 2

Followed by:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -8 
at Test.main(Test.java:10)

I know I can use String.format() to accomplish this, but I am not using that method because I need a method that works quickly while generating minimal garbage.  My question for the experts is... what can I change to make this work?

UPDATE

I made the changes suggested by Ted Hopp, and it worked perfectly in the test method.  I moved it over to my Android app, which converts the bytes to a MAC address into a char[] containing a formatted MAC.  I'm no longer getting negative numbers, but I am getting what appear to be random miscalculations.  Here is the method I am using:

```
static final char[] parser_hex_arr = "01234567890ABCDEF".toCharArray();
static final char[] parser_mac = "  :  :  :  :  :  ".toCharArray();

void parseMac() { 
    hex_sb.setLength(0);
    for (hex_counter = 0; hex_counter < 6; hex_counter++) {
        hex_sb.append(String.format("%02X", parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip + hex_counter]));
        if (!(hex_counter == 5)) {
                hex_sb.append(":");
        }
    }

    parser_mac[0] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip] >> 4) & 0x0f ];
    parser_mac[1] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip] & 0xf) ];
    parser_mac[3] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip + 1] >> 4) & 0x0f ];
    parser_mac[4] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip + 1] & 0xf) ];
    parser_mac[6] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip + 2]  >> 4) & 0x0f ];
    parser_mac[7] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip + 2] & 0xf) ];
    parser_mac[9] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip + 3]  >> 4) & 0x0f ];
    parser_mac[10] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip + 3] & 0xf) ];
    parser_mac[12] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip + 4] >> 4) & 0x0f ];
    parser_mac[13] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip + 4] & 0xf) ];
    parser_mac[15] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip + 5] >> 4) & 0x0f ];
    parser_mac[16] = parser_hex_arr[ (parser_packet_bytes[parser_skip + 5] & 0xf) ];

    Log.i("PARSER", "StringBuilder.getString() = " + hex_sb.toString() + " | parser_mac = " + String.valueOf(parser_mac));

    formatted_mac = String.valueOf(parser_mac);
}
```

parser_packet_bytes is a byte[] array of bytes of a packet, parser_skip is an int containing an offset where the byte is located, and hex_sb is a StringBuilder.  The output from StringBuilder.toString() should be the same as String.valueOf(parser_mac)... but it isn't.  Here is an example:

> I/PARSER  (10860): StringBuilder.getString() = AC:22:0B:40:70:41 | parser_mac = 0B:22:0A:40:70:41
>
> I/PARSER  (10860): StringBuilder.getString() = C8:F7:33:0E:7E:AF | parser_mac = B8:E7:33:0D:7D:0E
>
> I/PARSER  (10860): StringBuilder.getString() = 58:6D:8F:BA:F5:81 | parser_mac = 58:6C:8E:A0:E5:81
>
> I/PARSER  (10860): StringBuilder.getString() = AC:22:0B:40:70:41 | parser_mac = 0B:22:0A:40:70:41

My next question is... why don't they match?  Thanks for any ideas that you may have.

Comment: Your edit is a totally new question (very weird behavior, too). I suggest posting it as a separate question. The new question won't get any attention tacked onto the end of this question. (Also, I don't see why it should be behaving that way; the question needs broader attention.)

Answer (score 8):

This is due to sign extension. Byte values are signed in Java, so anything over 0x7f is treated as a negative value. The bit shift operators convert both operands to integers before doing the shift. You need to mask the bottom byte off after integer promotion. For example:

```
((bytes[i] & 0xff) >> 4)
```

or

```
((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f)
```

instead of

```
(bytes[i] >> 4)
```

Comment: The second option is what you want in my opinion.  The first only works because it widens the value to an `int` in the process.  (The latter does too, but wouldn't need to).  Not a big deal since you're using in an `int` context anyway, but I think the latter is more self-documenting.

Comment: Java also has `>>>`, which always shifts in a zero bit even on signed numbers.

Comment: @MarkPeters - Six of one, half a dozen of the other. Both work because of the rules of the language.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - That's irrelevant to this problem. Using `>>>` would only get the high four bits to be 0. OP needs the high 28 bits to be 0.

Comment: @Ted: You're right, it's just a question of transparency.  Normally when I do the former I use `0x0ff` to make it abundantly clear.  But it's more because I personally need reminding when it comes to signed bit operations.

Comment: @MarkPeters - Yeah, the second option makes it clearer that the objective is to get a 4-bit value.

Answer (score 4):

java will bit extend when widening bytes to integer so you need to mask out the high order bits.

```
    System.out.println("First nibble: " + hex_val[(bytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f]);
    System.out.println("Second nibble: " + hex_val[(bytes[i] & 0x0f)]);
```